# Springboot query MongoDb Atlas search index

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, full-text-indexing

I have a MongoDb that has a collection of cars which includes fields like:

```
price: "49,500"
brand: "Mercedes-benz",
model: "E 400d"
power: "340 PS"
engine: "2995 cmc"
etc.
```

On my Springboot backend I want to create and endpoint which will return search suggestions based on the user input.

For example if the user searches for:
"**mer**", "**Mer**", "**Mercedes**", "**Mercedes benz**","Nercedes"(fuzzy search N instead of M), "**benz**", "**E400**"(without spaces and missing d), "**E 400**"(missing d), "**400d**"(missing E), "**E400 d**" (missplaced whitespace), "**E400d**"( no whitespaces) and other similar use cases I want to return to the user the correct results.

My current index:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": false,
    "fields": {
      "brand": {
        "maxGrams": 20,
        "tokenization": "edgeGram",
        "type": "autocomplete"
      },
      "model": {
        "maxGrams": 20,
        "tokenization": "edgeGram",
        "type": "autocomplete"
      },
      "power": {
        "maxGrams": 20,
        "tokenization": "edgeGram",
        "type": "autocomplete"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example java query:
val collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("cars")

```
    val agg = Document(
            "\$search", Document(
            "autocomplete", Document("query", searchInput)
            .append("path", "brand")
            .append("fuzzy", Document("maxEdits", 1))
    )
 )

    collection.aggregate(
            listOf(
                    agg,
                    limit(20),
                    project(fields(include("brand", "model", "power")))
            )
    )
```